# How can I measure the distance between many polygon features and either another polygon or a line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, distance, measurements

I often have to manually measure the distance between a single site and other sites around it, but obviously this can get long-winded and I feel like there must be a much more efficient way of doing it using QGIS.

I need to be able to measure the distance between the closest points of each feature within a polygon vector layer to my site boundary, which is also normally a polygon layer.

Comment: Do you think this will be helpful? It looks like it could be. http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/nearest_neighbor_analysis.html

Comment: With point shapefiles, calculating distances is great! When it comes to lines and polygons, QGIS will calculate distances from their **centroid**, not from the closest geometry. You could try using the GRASS tool [v.distance](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.distance.html) from the _Processing Toolbox_ although I would recommend importing your shapefiles into [PostGIS](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/spatial_databases/index.html).